# UWP EmailMessage linebreak/new line?

Tags: c#, email, newline, uwp, line-breaks

I'm looking for a way to put linebreaks in the body of an `EmailMessage()` in my UWP app.

I already tried with `"\n"`, `\r\n`, `Environment.NewLine`, `<br>`, `<br />`, and every time it gets omitted whether on Desktop, on Mobile or both. I tried with Outlook and Gmail.

I'm using VS2015 update 3.

Thanks.

Edit: here's the code

```
    public static async Task ComposeEmail(string address, string messageSubject, StorageFile attachmentFile)
    {
        var emailMessage = new EmailMessage();
        emailMessage.Subject = messageSubject;

        var lineBreak = Environment.NewLine;
        string body = lineBreak + lineBreak + lineBreak + lineBreak + lineBreak + lineBreak + textLoader.GetString("EmailPleaseDontCut") + lineBreak + Info.GetAllInfos();
        emailMessage.Body = body;

        if (attachmentFile != null)
        {
            var stream = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(attachmentFile);

            var attachment = new EmailAttachment(attachmentFile.Name, stream);

            emailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        }

        emailMessage.To.Add(new EmailRecipient(address));

        await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post all of your code for the emailing? I just did this a couple days ago with \r\n and it works fine

Comment: Hi @AnthonyRussell! could you please take a look to the above code and tell me what's wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Why Not use String Builder and Append Environment.NewLine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am showing an email like this and it's breaking it into two lines in the body

```
 EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage()
 {
       Subject = "App Feedback " + Package.Current.DisplayName + " " + ApplicationServices.CurrentDevice,
       Body = "First Line\r\nSecondLine" 
 };

 emailMessage.To.Add(new EmailRecipient() { Address = "admin@DotNetRussell.com" });
 await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
```

I think I read the same article you did on sending emails in UWP. That code you posted looks identical to it. That example sucked and it was wrong. The way I posted works way better.